# MySQL running time

Tags: mysql

So I have a table bj10dcmegablast with 20 million rows. Now I want to do a query as

```
select *, max(qEnd - qStart) 
from 
     (select qFileID,qLocus,qTranscript,qLength,sFileId,sLocus,sTranscript,
sLength,qStart,qEnd,sStart,sEnd
      from bj10dcmegablast
      where (qLocus, qTranscript)
      in     
        (select distinct qLocus, qTranscript
     from
        (select qLocus, qTranscript, count(distinct sFileID) as counts
         from bj10dcmegablast
        group by qLocus, qTranscript
         having counts > 6) as middle1)) as middle2
group by qLocus,sLocus;
```

I have no idea how long it will take. I ran this query for one hour. Not finished yet.

So I did some test:

```
select qLocus, qTranscript, count(distinct sFileID) as counts
from bj10dcmegablast
group by qLocus, qTranscript
having counts > 6
```

This takes 40 seconds.

```
select distinct qLocus, qTranscript
 from
    (select qLocus, qTranscript, count(distinct sFileID) as counts
     from bj10dcmegablast
    group by qLocus, qTranscript
     having counts > 6) as middle1;
```

This one takes 2 mins.

Anyone can tell how long you think the full query will last?

Comment: Post the results of the EXPLAIN statement so we can have a look at the MySQL execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

The `IN` clause can be inefficient in MySQL.  Try doing this with an explicit join:

```
select *, max(qEnd - qStart) 
from (select qFileID, qLocus, qTranscript, qLength, sFileId, sLocus, sTranscript,
             sLength, qStart, qEnd, sStart, sEnd
      from bj10dcmegablast
     ) b join
     (select qLocus, qTranscript, count(distinct sFileID) as counts
      from bj10dcmegablast
      group by qLocus, qTranscript
      having counts > 6
     ) as middle2
     on b.qLocus = middle2.qLocus and b.qTranscript = b.qTranscript
group by qLocus, sLocus;
```

In this version, you don't need the "middle1" alias, because you are already grouping by the two fields.  They should be distinct.